# Numerically find amplitude and phase in R

Tags: r

I need to ask a follow-up question to this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449290/algorithmically-get-amplitude-and-phase-of-sine-wave

My objective is to find the amplitude and phase of some signal. For a better understanding I now want to assume that this signal is a simple sine wave.

The code that I currently have is:

```
t <- seq(0, 100, length.out = 1000)
s <- sin(t)
qplot(t, s, geom = "line")

f <- fft(s)
a2 <- Mod(f/length(s))
qplot(t, a2, geom = "line")
```

As far as I understood it, the second plot now visualises the double-sided Fourier transform, right? So, what do I have to do to end up with `amplitude = 1`? From looking at the second plot I would need to add the two peaks...?

And, regarding the phase. I know that I would have to use something like `p2 = Arg(f)`, but how do I end up with `phase = 0`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Correct formula for sine wave is
$$
A\cdot \sin(2\pi\cdot f\cdot t + \phi)
$$
where $A$ is amplitude, $f$ is frequency and $\phi$ is phase.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40786253/5215145) on stackoverflow I showed a function, that can help you to understand `fft()` better.

Comment: yes...which is exactly what I used for $A=1$, $f=1/2\pi$ and $\phi=0$.

Comment: Looking at your function, I would need to `max(Mod(fk))` to get my amplitude and the last value of `Arg(fk)` to get my phase, right? But apart from that, could you explain what you did to `fk` after the `fft` and why?

Comment: Discrete Fourier transform gives you a vector f. First element is so called zero-frequency, should be a sum of a signal. The first half of f ( f[2:(n/2)], where n us length(f) ) contains positive-frequency terms, second half - negative ones. So for ease of interpretation I take only first half. You should plot Mod(fur) ~ freq from my function, you will get a value ~1 near frequency 1/2*pi. It would be a amplitude spectrum. Same for Arg(fur) for phase - it should be zero on whole interval.